# PL/SQL Trigger not finding values to analyze

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm creating a PL/SQL Trigger that gives me an error if the date_fin < date_begin. (Im new to triggers.)

My problem is that when testing Im getting `ORA-01403: no Data found`. Id say the trigger has found no data to analyze but my table contains values.

Does my error come from my trigger format?

Here is my code:

```
--TRIGGER1
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER verifDate
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON PROJET FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE date_debut projet.dateDebut%TYPE;
date_fin projet.dateFin%TYPE;
pragma autonomous_transaction;
BEGIN
    Select projet.dateDebut into date_debut from projet where date_debut=:new.dateDebut;
    Select projet.dateFin into date_fin from projet where date_fin=:new.datefin;
        IF date_fin < date_debut
        THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20100, 'Mauvaise date') ;
        END IF;
END;
```

Tests:

```
--TEST1.1
INSERT INTO PROJET (idProjet, idClient, nomProjet, dateDebut, dateFin, idResponsable)
VALUES (4,355,'Projet Test', '01/12/2020', '30/12/2019', 3851);


--TEST1.2
UPDATE PROJET
SET dateFIN = '01/09/2003' , dateDebut = '31/12/2019'
WHERE Projet.idProjet=2;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you just want to assert that `dateDebut < dateFIN`? If so why are you using a trigger and not a check constraint? Also, why an autonomous transaction?

Comment: @MT0 Yeah verify if its true so the -if- gets executed. Its part of an assignment on triggers so I must do it this way. But the problem is wether its true or not my trigger is not working and giving me that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the error comes from the trigger because it is a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger so the row does not yet exist in the table but you are trying to use `SELECT` to get data matching the row and it fails with a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception.

Instead, you should use the `:NEW` (and, if you need it, `:OLD`) record:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER verifDate
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON PROJET FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.dateFIN < :NEW.dateDebut THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20100, 'Mauvaise date') ;
  END IF;
END verifDate;
/
```

However, this should be done using a `CHECK` constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE projet ADD CONSTRAINT projet__datedebut_lte_datefin__chk
  CHECK (dateDebut < dateFin);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c7f25dc9ce84ce88341a8468cab7a507)*

Comment: Thanks, Its very helpful. Id like to know if the fonction you wrote should be enough or do I add the -:new- part in my fonction (Ill delete the select part of course? Also if I understood correctly what you said I shouldnt use Select if I have a -BEFORE-?

Comment: @LIsa The trigger is from the `CREATE` until the `/` and you need it all. Not sure what you are asking about a function as there is no function in my answer. As for the last part, if your trigger is working with values from the single row that you have inserted or updated then you should be using the `:NEW` and `:OLD` records to reference the new and old data from that row and should not use `SELECT` statements; `SELECT` statements would be when you wanted to use data from other rows/tables in your trigger.